# How do you query inside a query in db_select?

Tags: drupal-7

```
id  reference_id   
1    3             

2    9             

3    6       

4    2

4    1
```

I want to query the above and get the list based on desc for column 'id'
and then I wan to group the result by value in reference id and limit to two answers

so the output would be

```
4   1

4   2
```

below is my code but I am not getting anywhere

```
 $account = user_load($uid); // had to load the user to get the username for the below query
    $query1 = db_select('eck_eventlog', 'e');
    $query1->condition('e.type', 'eventlog');
    $query1->condition('e.reference_id', $flagged_nodes, 'IN');
    $query1->condition('e.username', $account->name); // added this as for user type was getting   the wrong result
    $query1->fields('e')
      ->orderBy('id', 'DESC');

    $query = db_select($query1,'t');
    $query->groupBy('t.reference_id');
    if ($limit != '') {
      $query->range(0, $limit);
    }
    $result = $query->execute();
    return $result;
```

Comment: I don't follow how you get from your first output to your second - you haven't grouped by anything, you've just thrown away 4 of the 6 results.

Comment: So, you just want to *sort* by the reference_id? "Group By" in SQL means "generate a single row for each distinct value of", but all the values of reference_id in your example are distinct.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at this page for an example: http://sqlzoo.net/wiki/SELECT_within_SELECT_Tutorial

Basically the output of a SELECT can go into another SELECT.

It really helps if you use proper naming with 'AS'.